# the arrays won't add up the votes correctly?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that will tally votes from each counties up to 4 for two candidates. Basically it will ask you to add the votes in each counties for each candidate. Then it will tally the votes and display the winner. This mostly works but It won't add up the votes and declare the winner correctly? I suspect it is something wrong with the loop at line 37 to line 40.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int tier1();

int main(void)
{
 int return_val = tier1();
 if (return_val < 0) // print an error
 return 0;
}
int tier1(){
 int votes[7];
 int i, j, N; // variables
 int k = 0;
 for (i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
  cout << "county" << i << "\n"; // lists the 4 counties/candidates
  for (j=0; j<2; j++)
   {
      cout << "How many votes did the candidate " << j << " get?\n";
      N=0;
       cin >> N;
      votes[k++] = N;;
   }
   if (votes[k-2] + votes[k-1] > 100) //checking if it goes over 100 votes
   {
    cout << "County has too many votes. Exiting!\n"; // Print an error
    exit(1);
   }

 }

 int candidate0Votes = 0; //resetting 
 int candidate1Votes = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {
 cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
 cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
 candidate0Votes += votes[i+1];
 candidate1Votes += votes[i+1];
 }
 if (candidate0Votes > candidate1Votes){
 cout << "The winner of the election is candidate 0.\n";
 }
 else
 {
 cout << "The winner of the election is candidate 1.\n";
 }
 cout << "Here is the voting results:\n";
 cout << "candidate 0 got ";
 cout << candidate0Votes;
 cout << " votes\n";
 cout << "candidate 1 got ";
 cout << candidate1Votes;
 cout << " votes\n";

 return 0;

}
```

Let me know if there is any other revision that I should do!
Thanks!

Comment: which arrays? the line 37 one?

Comment: Never mind. I assume it's a language barrier.

Comment: is this your homework?

Answer (score 2):

Your votes array is short.

It seems you have 4x2 entries, but the array is only 7 elements.

Here's a version that I could live with:

<kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cd4e3e917241dfd)**</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int tier1();

int main(void) {
    return tier1();
}

static int getnumber(std::string prompt) {
    if (!std::cin)
        return 0;

    int i;
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::cin >> i;

    while(!std::cin) {
        if (std::cin.eof()) {
            exit(1); 
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(1<<30, '\n');
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::cin >> i;
    }

    return i;
}

#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int tier1() {
    using namespace std;
    using county = int;

    static constexpr int number_of_counties   = 4;
    static constexpr int number_of_candidates = 2;

    map<county, size_t[number_of_candidates]> votes;

    for (int cty = 0; cty < number_of_counties; cty++) {
        for (int cand = 0; cand < number_of_candidates; cand++) {
            votes[cty][cand] = getnumber("How many votes did the candidate " + to_string(cand) + " get in county " + to_string(cty) + "? ");
        }
        if (std::accumulate(begin(votes[cty]), end(votes[cty]), 0u) > 100)
            cout << "County has too many votes. Exiting!\n"; // Print an error
    }

    size_t totals[number_of_candidates] = { 0 };

    for(auto& cty: votes) {
        for (auto in = begin(cty.second), accum = begin(totals); accum < end(totals);) {
            *accum++ += *in++;
        }
    }

    auto winner = max_element(begin(totals), end(totals));

    cout << "The winner of the election is candidate " << distance(totals, winner) << "\n";

    cout << "Here is the voting results:\n";
    for (int cand = 0; cand < number_of_candidates; cand++) {
        cout << "candidate " << cand << " got " << totals[cand] << " votes\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh okay, so I need to remove the [i+1] to [i] for the candidate 1?

Comment: No, you need to replace 7 by 8. And then fix the way you index "behing" k because you're using indices < 0

Answer (score 1):

In addition to sehe's observation, I also see you have the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
  cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
  candidate0Votes += votes[i+1];
  candidate1Votes += votes[i+1];
}
```

This should probably be (after you make your array size 8):

```
// Loop through all countries
for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 2)
{
  // Print out the candidate's votes per country
  cout << votes[i] << "\n";
  cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
  // Total up each candidate's votes
  candidate0Votes += votes[i];
  candidate1Votes += votes[i+1];
}
```

Comment: This is helpful! I am still having problem with the program. It seems that I cannot get the candidate 0 to win? and the total votes still doesn't add up correctly

Comment: Can you try a sample input?  It might help to try the following: Candidate 1 gets 1, 2, 3, 2 votes, and candidate 2 gets 10, 20, 30, and 20 votes.  This way, we can see if anything is getting "crossed" in the addition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. The array size was changed to 8, and the for loop in line 37 to 40 was also modified.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int tier1();

int main(void)
{
    int return_val = tier1();
    if (return_val < 0) // print an error
        return 0;
}
int tier1(){
    int votes[8];
    int i, j, N; // variables
    int k = 0;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "county" << i << "\n"; // lists the 4 counties/candidates
        for (j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            cout << "How many votes did the candidate " << j << " get?\n";
            N=0;
            cin >> N;
            votes[k++] = N;;
        }
        if (votes[k-2] + votes[k-1] > 100) //checking if it goes over 100 votes
        {
            cout << "County has too many votes. Exiting!\n"; // Print an error
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    int candidate0Votes = 0; //resetting
    int candidate1Votes = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i+=2)
    {
        cout << votes[i] << "\n";
        cout << votes[i+1] << "\n";
        candidate0Votes += votes[i];
        candidate1Votes += votes[i+1];
    }
    if (candidate0Votes > candidate1Votes){
        cout << "The winner of the election is candidate 0.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The winner of the election is candidate 1.\n";
    }
    cout << "Here is the voting results:\n";
    cout << "candidate 0 got ";
    cout << candidate0Votes;
    cout << " votes\n";
    cout << "candidate 1 got ";
    cout << candidate1Votes;
    cout << " votes\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The winner of the election is candidate 1.   
Here is the voting results:   
candidate 0 got 16 votes   
candidate 1 got 20 votes

Comment: @Puppy I just want to make less changes to this code. Anyway, downvote is fine.

Comment: @sehe `k` is 2 when first arrives at the if condition. What's the problem?

Comment: @OldPanda Ah. Thank you for making me realize my mistake. I got the wrong idea there. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @sehe That's OK. You also inspired me to think deeper into my code.

Comment: I've fixed the mistake I made interpreting the OP's code in my answer now too :/ +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved suggestion which structures the code in a way that makes more sense (altough my original suggestion is probably easier):

You could use a two dimensional array as follows:

```
int votes[2][4]; //Store the votes in the format [candidate 0 or 1][country 0 to 3]
```

The loop in question would then become:

```
// Loop through all countries
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    // Print out the candidate's votes per country
    cout << votes[0][i] << "\n";
    cout << votes[1][i] << "\n";

    // Total up each candidate's votes
    candidate0Votes += votes[0][i];
    candidate1Votes += votes[1][i];
}
```

The rest of the code would need to be modified to adapt to that structure as well.  Since this could be a bit confusing, I left it as a separate answer.  It is probably a bit better way to structure the program, but my original answer should fix the problem.

Comment: Make `votes` a struct and you could loose the opaque double indexing.

Comment: @Puppy: I disagree -- it's not entirely fair, because the OP never mentioned it, and all other values are constant as well, and it's not the *reason* for the OPs program to fail. You might as well downvote because "in C++ everything ought to be a class".

Comment: ... says the guy who suggested using a struct :) That's seems a bit mixed there. Of course I agree.

Comment: @sehe: uh sure. Going from single indexing to double indexing is less clear than to a struct, as it adds to opaqueness. But throwing the entire original code away and starting a-new with a class would be better.